# Pdf won't update/show when quick-building in TexMaker

Tags: texmaker, mactex, mac

I am running TexMaker 4.4.1 on a Macbook with El Capitan iOS. It seems like the problem started after updating my Macbook.

When i quick build no errors happen and no Pdf is showing.

Quick build is set to PdfLaTex + View PDF

The only way i can see the Pdf is the View PDF next to the Quick Build option. But it shows a pdf containing files not even activated or existing anymore in my master.

---

**Things i have tried:**

Delete PDF (Results in a PDF file not found error)

Delete all aux logs etc on all documents (it won't build new aux logs etc)

Delete all text only having a chapter or blank page (no errors but not showing a pdf)

Run all type of build options 10 times (nothing changed)

Changing the quick build command in preferences to the one with a lot of commands while building and building it 10 times, which takes quite some time :P (Nothing changed)

Making a conflict by changing a file path to force an build error ( Quickbuild will make errors and won't build it. But i can view the old PDF with the view pdf option next to quick build, showing text not even existing in my files)

Tried using a build subdirectory for output files in preferences (Error in building)

What ever i do it won't show a pdf after quick building, only when i use the view pdf option, which then shows an old pdf file.

Comment: There has been a lot of problems caused by some changes made in relation to the El Capitan update, have you looked at some of those questions? (http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=capitan)

Comment: Ill take a look at that now, i didn't even that one, thanks a lot ill look at it:)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.